# Offset and fetch in a delete statement

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle19c

I want to delete some specific rows based on two dynamic parameters, P1 and P2 (Numbers)

Using a simple Select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (conditions) OFFSET P1 ROWS FETCH NEXT P2 ROWS ONLY;
```

I simply want to delete these rows and I can't find a correct way to do it.
What I'm doing right now is somthing like, and it doesn't look good:

```
DELETE TABLE WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE (conditions) OFFSET P1 ROWS FETCH NEXT P2 ROWS ONLY);
```

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` you'll delete (select) some random rows BTW. Table in relational database represent relations, which are a special form of (multi) set and thus have no order. Without an explicit `ORDER BY` the DBMS is free to return the result of a query in **any** order.

Comment: Your delete statement looks fine to me. It deletes the same amount of rows as the select statement alone shows. With a determnistic `ORDER BY` clause, these would even be the same rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the primary key or `ROWID` to access the rows:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE rowid IN
(SELECT rowid FROM mytable WHERE (conditions) OFFSET p1 ROWS FETCH NEXT p2 ROWS ONLY);
```

When running the query repeatedly, you will end up with a table consisting of p1 rows. But as mentioned by sticky bit in the request comments: without an `ORDER BY` these rows will be arbitrary.